# How to pass environment variables to docker-compose's applications

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to pass environment variables that is readable by applications spin up by `docker-compose up`.

What is the proper way of using `docker-compose up` with varying configuration settings?

I don't want to use `.env` & `environment:` config as the environment variables are changing frequently & it is insecure to save tokens in a file.

`docker-compose run -e` does work a bit, but loses many.
It does not map the ports that defined in `docker-compose.yml` services.
Also multiple services are defined in `docker-compose.yml` and I don't want to use `depends_on` just because `docker-compose up` doesn't work.

Let's say I define service in `docker-compose.yml`

```
    service-a:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: DockerfileA
        command: node serviceA.js
```

In my `serviceA.js`, I simply use the environment variable:

```
console.log("This is ", process.env.KEY, "running in service A");
```

---

When I run `docker-compose run -e KEY=DockerComposeRun service-a`
I do get the environment variable KEY read by serviceA.js

```
This is  DockerComposeRun running in service A
```

However I could only get one single service running.

---

I could have use `environment:` in `docker-compose.yml`

```
environment:
  - KEY=DockerComposeUp
```

But in my use case, each docker compose would have different environment variable values, meaning I would need to edit the file each time before I do docker-compose.

Also, not only single service would use the same environment variable, `.env` even done a better job, but it is not desired.

---

There doesn't seem to be a way to do the same for `docker-compose up`
I have tried `KEY=DockerComposeUp docker-compose up`,
but what I get is `undefined` .

Export doesn't work for me as well, it seems they are all about using environment variable for `docker-compose.yml` instead of for the applications in container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To safely pass sensitive configuration data to your containers you can use [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/). Everything passed through Secrets is encrypted.

You can create and manage secrets using the commands below:

```
docker secret create
docker secret inspect
docker secret ls
docker secret rm
```

And use them in your docker-compose file, either referring to existing secrets (external) or use a file:

```
secrets:
  my_first_secret:
    file: ./secret_data
  my_second_secret:
    external: true
```

Comment: This seems interesting! Thanks for letting me know, I'll look into it ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use environment like this:

```
    service-a:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: DockerfileA
        command: node serviceA.js
        environment:
            KEY=DockerComposeRun
```

Refer at: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned, I don't want some environment variables to be written into files, including `docker-compose.yml` because they are frequently changing at each instances of docker compose and it is insecure.